# Controller Returns Mysterious View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `Details` action in `SampleController`:

```
public ActionResult Details(int sampleNumber)
{
    var sample = (Sample)Session["sample"];
    if (sample == null)
    {
        var pallet = (Pallet)Session["pallet"];

        sample = pallet.Samples.First(s
            => s.SampleNo.Equals(sampleNumber));

        if (sample.Defects.Count < 1) // Postback issue?
        {
            var access = new Access();

            sample.Defects = access.GetDefects(pallet.Grv.GRVNo,
                pallet.PalletSeq, sampleNumber);
            sample.GetImagePaths();
            sample.Pallet = pallet;

            Session["sample"] = sample;
        }
    }

    return View(sample);
}
```

And this `Update` action:

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Sample sample)
{
    var pallet = (Pallet)Session["pallet"];

    sample.Pallet = pallet;
    sample.SaveImages(files);

    access.UpdateSample(sample);
    access.UpdateDefects(sample);

    Session["sample"] = sample;

    return View("Details", sample);
}
```

I am trying to debug an issue, but somehow the line `return View("Details", sample);` is not calling the above `Details` action (the breakpoint does not stop the code).

It does return a view of the selected `sample`, but none of the operations present in `Details` are occurring.

I tried changing the `return` statement to

```
return View("Details", sample.SampleNo);
```

To match the signature of `Details`, but then I get :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MVCQCPage.Models.Sample'.

How is that possible? the `Details` action does NOT ask for a `Sample` param, so why does this not just return `Details` and pass in the `sampleNo` (`int`) value?

Note that the above `Details` action is the only method of that name in `SampleController`.

Comment: I think you want to user RedirectToAction and not return View. Pls read the difference between the two online

Comment: Does "Details" view exists under views folder underneath the controller name (Views\Sample\Details.cshtml)?

Comment: @sam Yes i does, I use that view when a user just wants to view the details of a `Sample`. However, I also want to redirect to that after they create or edit a `Sample`

Comment: so, your Update action is a POST action. As others suggested, you will need to use RedirectAction in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers mention, I need to use `RedirectToAction`.

However, i also need to pass in a named `sampleNumber` parameter:

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", new { @sampleNumber = sample.SampleNo });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do **RedirectToAction**

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Sample sample)
{
 var pallet = (Pallet)Session["pallet"];

  sample.Pallet = pallet;
  sample.SaveImages(files);

  access.UpdateSample(sample);
  access.UpdateDefects(sample);

  Session["sample"] = sample;

  return RedirectToAction("Details", sample.SampleNo);
}
```

Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: I am getting `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sampleNumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MVCQCPage.Controllers.SampleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.` when I try this.

Comment: I also tried changing `sample` to `sample.SampleNo` but I get `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'sampleNumber' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'MVCQCPage.Controllers.SampleController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.`

Comment: @Bassie, I think sample.SampleNo is nullable int,so change your parameter to **public ActionResult Details(int? sampleNumber)**

Comment: Okay I worked it out. `SampleNo` is not nullable, I just had to pas in a named paramater `return RedirectToAction("Details", new { @sampleNumber = sample.SampleNo });`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **RedirectToAction**:

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, Sample sample)
{
    var pallet = (Pallet)Session["pallet"];

    sample.Pallet = pallet;
    sample.SaveImages(files);

    access.UpdateSample(sample);
    access.UpdateDefects(sample);

    Session["sample"] = sample;

    return RedirectToAction("Details", sample);
}
```

The View() method returns the specified view without invoking the Details Action, however the RedirectToAction() method redirects to the specified action not the View().